# How to load JSON data and set into expandablelistview in viewpager dynamically

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager, expandablelistview

My Json Data (link for 1 page) http://192.168.0.2/AIRIS/api/Main/GetCateenOrderCategoryItemListDetail?CategoryID=35

```
    {
    "SBL": [
        {
            "SubCategoryID": 37,
            "SubCategoryName": "Buscuites",
            "SubCategoryItemList": [
                {
                    "ItemID": 23,
                    "SubCategoryID": 37,
                    "ItemName": "Orio Buscuites",
                    "ImageUrl": "http://192.168.0.222/HRISWebAPI/ClientResources/CntRowMaterial/23.jpg",
                    "Qty": 1,
                    "DefaultPrice": 10,
                    "Price": null,
                    "Discount": null,
                    "FinalPrice": 10
                },
                {
                    "ItemID": 29,
                    "SubCategoryID": 37,
                    "ItemName": "Parle-G",
                    "ImageUrl": "http://192.168.0.222/HRISWebAPI/ClientResources/CntRowMaterial/29.jpg",
                    "Qty": 1,
                    "DefaultPrice": 5,
                    "Price": null,
                    "Discount": null,
                    "FinalPrice": 5
                },
                {
                    "ItemID": 30,
                    "SubCategoryID": 37,
                    "ItemName": "BornBorn",
                    "ImageUrl": "http://192.168.0.222/HRISWebAPI/ClientResources/CntRowMaterial/30.jpg",
                    "Qty": 1,
                    "DefaultPrice": 25,
                    "Price": null,
                    "Discount": null,
                    "FinalPrice": 25
                },
                {
                    "ItemID": 31,
                    "SubCategoryID": 37,
                    "ItemName": "Hide & Sick",
                    "ImageUrl": "http://192.168.0.222/HRISWebAPI/ClientResources/CntRowMaterial/31.jpg",
                    "Qty": 1,
                    "DefaultPrice": 20,
                    "Price": null,
                    "Discount": null,
                    "FinalPrice": 20
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SubCategoryID": 38,
            "SubCategoryName": "Tea",
            "SubCategoryItemList": [
                {
                    "ItemID": 18,
                    "SubCategoryID": 38,
                    "ItemName": "Ice Tea",
                    "ImageUrl": "http://192.168.0.222/HRISWebAPI/ClientResources/CntRowMaterial/18.jpg",
                    "Qty": 1,
                    "DefaultPrice": 0,
                    "Price": null,
                    "Discount": null,
                    "FinalPrice": 0
                },
                {
                    "ItemID": 19,
                    "SubCategoryID": 38,
                    "ItemName": "Lempon Tea",
                    "ImageUrl": "http://192.168.0.222/HRISWebAPI/ClientResources/CntRowMaterial/19.jpg",
                    "Qty": 1,
                    "DefaultPrice": 20,
                    "Price": null,
                    "Discount": null,
                    "FinalPrice": 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to load JSON data and set into expandablelistview which placed on each page of viewpager where data came dynamically to set expandablelistview using also getter and setter mehod in android

TabMenuActivity.java (which extends ActinBarActivity)
from this class controll pass from activity to fragment which shown below in this class method of onPostExecute()

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        if(result == true){
            if (categoryList.size() > 0) {

                AppConstants.CATEGORY_LIST = categoryList;

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                SlidingContentFragment fragment = new SlidingContentFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CategoryListJSONAsyncTask:Unable to fetch data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

SlidingContentFragment.java (this class extends fragment )

NOTE: In this class method of subclass SamplePagerAdaptor.java of instantiateItem() method where i taken ExpandableListview for display data.

```
public class SlidingContentFragment extends Fragment {
    static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingContentFragment";

// store category list from Conastant list, used for to display pagetitle

List<String> catList = AppConstants.CATEGORY_LIST;
private static String[] tmpId  = {"35","36","41","42","43","44","45","46"};

ExpandableListView exListCategory;


private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;

/**
 * A {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager} which will be used in conjunction with the {@link SlidingTabLayout} above.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
//private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter; // added new
private SamplePagerAdapter myAdapter;

public SlidingContentFragment() {
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View slideRootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sliding_content, container, false);

    return slideRootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)
    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    this.myAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(); // added new
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this.myAdapter);
    // END_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)



    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)
    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
    // it's PagerAdapter set.
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

}

public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    // This holds all the currently displayable views, in order from left to right.
    private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return catList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o){
        return o == view;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return catList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition (Object object)
    {
        int index = views.indexOf (object);
        if (index == -1)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        else
            return index;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        //return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        //ListView listCategory = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        exListCategory = (ExpandableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.myExpandableListView);

        new CategoryJSONAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.0.2/AIRIS/api/Main/GetCateenOrderCategoryItemListDetail?CategoryID="+tmpId[position].toString().trim());

        Log.i("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.i("catList",String.valueOf(catList.get(position)));

        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }


}

public class CategoryJSONAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                return result;
            }
            return result;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> listParent = fetchResponse(result.replace("\n","").trim());

            for (Object obj : listParent){
                if(obj.getClass() == CategoryParentItemList.class){
                    CategoryParentItemList p = (CategoryParentItemList)obj;
                    System.out.println("P-ItemName: "+ p.subCategoryName);
                }
            }

            CategoryItemListAdapter adapter;adapter = new CategoryItemListAdapter(SlidingContentFragment.this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), listParent);
            exListCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}

public ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> fetchResponse(String result)
{
    ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> listParent = new ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList>();
    if (!result.equals(""))
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("SBL");

            CategoryParentItemList parent = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                ArrayList<CategoryChildListItem> childrens = new ArrayList<CategoryChildListItem>();
                childrens.clear();
                CategoryChildListItem child;

                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("SCI: " + object.getInt("SubCategoryID"));
                System.out.println("SCN: " + object.getString("SubCategoryName"));

                JSONArray subItemArray = object.getJSONArray("SubCategoryItemList");

                if (subItemArray.length() > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < subItemArray.length(); j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject subItemObject = subItemArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String strItemName = subItemObject.getString("ItemName");
                        String strDefaultPrice = subItemObject.getString("DefaultPrice");

                        child = new CategoryChildListItem(strItemName, strDefaultPrice);
                        childrens.add(child);

                        Log.i("strItemName", strItemName);
                        Log.i("strDefaultPrice", strDefaultPrice);
                    }
                    parent = new CategoryParentItemList(object.getString("SubCategoryName"),childrens);
                    listParent.add(parent);
                }

            }

            //CategoryItemListAdapter adapter = new CategoryItemListAdapter(this, listParent, listChild);
            //exListCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listParent;
}
}
```

CategoeyItemListAdapter

```
 public class CategoryItemListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> parentItemLists;

    static class ViewHolderGroup
    {
        TextView lblSubCategoryName;
    }

    static class ViewHolderChild
    {
        TextView lblItemName;
        TextView lblDefualtPrice;
    }

    public CategoryItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> listParent)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.parentItemLists = listParent;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {

        return parentItemLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {

        return parentItemLists.get(groupPosition).childList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {

        return parentItemLists.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {

        return parentItemLists.get(groupPosition).childList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {

        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {

        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CategoryParentItemList parentItem = (CategoryParentItemList)parentItemLists.get(groupPosition);
        ViewHolderGroup holderGroup = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header, null);
            holderGroup = new ViewHolderGroup();
            holderGroup.lblSubCategoryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);

        }
        else
        {
            holderGroup = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holderGroup.lblSubCategoryName.setText(parentItem.getSubCategoryName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CategoryParentItemList parentItem = (CategoryParentItemList)parentItemLists.get(groupPosition);
        CategoryChildListItem childItem = (CategoryChildListItem) parentItem.getChildList().get(childPosition);

        ViewHolderChild holder = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolderChild();
            holder.lblItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubItemName);
            holder.lblDefualtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvrRupees);
        }

        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.lblItemName.setText(childItem.getSubItemName());
        holder.lblDefualtPrice.setText(childItem.getDefaultPrice());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

//POJO Class for group and child data of expandable listview

```
public class CategoryParentItemList {


    private String subCategoryName;

    public CategoryParentItemList(String subCategoryName){
        this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
    }

    public String getSubCategoryName() {
        return subCategoryName;
    }

    public void setSubCategoryName(String subCategoryName) {
        this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
    }
}



public class CategoryChildListItem {

    private String subItemName;
    private String defaultPrice;

    public CategoryChildListItem(String subItemName, String defaultPrice) {
        this.subItemName = subItemName;
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
    }

    public String getSubItemName() {
        return subItemName;
    }

    public void setSubItemName(String subItemName) {
        this.subItemName = subItemName;
    }

    public String getDefaultPrice() {
        return defaultPrice;
    }

    public void setDefaultPrice(String defaultPrice) {
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
    }


}
```

// Now the above code is not any getting error but in viewpager of pages, some of pages not display the content and sometimes showing means its not persistent if any have idea please post it

Comment: Show your JSON data and also any code you have tried. As it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: sorry 4 late post of code....actually i'm at leave....for some reason.. I want to display expandable listview on each viewpager..i hv a ios app screenshot but reason of reputation i could not uploads the screenshot..

Comment: i add code and json data..please refer it @Squonk

Comment: post the code above @AmrutBidri

Comment: Wait for me to answer

Comment: ok..@AmrutBidri but here declared Adapter class for listview and my requirement for ExpandableListview  ( it's ExpandableListAdapter ).

Comment: @AmrutBidri i change my code....

Comment: what is at line SlidingContentFragment.java:241

Comment: fetchResponse() method call in @onPostExecute() method for fetch data from API based on passing url....i m getting problem to set data into expandablelistview and pojo class's  object to stored data. i would like to ask you @Amrut Bidri am i right at storing data into arraylist and object of POJO class in fetchResponse() method ?

Comment: try adding this line at the end of for loop of parent array **listParent.add(parent);**

Comment: after changed as you @AmrutBidri  saying getting error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference and what the intense for modification in POJO class ? please solve my problem as soon as possible.

Comment: @AmrutBidri there is error which was i got..it solved now..but sometimes pages not display the content and sometimes it shoeing.

Comment: @AmrutBidri have you any idea about sometimes the content of pages not showing ?

Comment: your may be reaching into exception. check the exceptions and try to resolve

Comment: there are not showing an error all data are fetch from api ( tracing the code ) but, it sometimes hide and display like that happen

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt change your POJO classess as below:

```
public class CategoryParentItemList {

private String subCategoryName;
private int subCategoryID;
ArrayList<CategoryChildListItem> childList=new ArrayList<CategoryChildListItem>();

public CategoryParentItemList(String subCategoryName){
    this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
}

public String getSubCategoryName() {
    return subCategoryName;
}

public void setSubCategoryName(String subCategoryName) {
    this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
}

}
```

and you child item as below:

```
public class CategoryChildListItem {

private String subItemName;
private String defaultPrice;

public CategoryChildListItem(String subItemName, String defaultPrice) {
    this.subItemName = subItemName;
    this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
}

public String getSubItemName() {
    return subItemName;
}

public void setSubItemName(String subItemName) {
    this.subItemName = subItemName;
}

public String getDefaultPrice() {
    return defaultPrice;
}

public void setDefaultPrice(String defaultPrice) {
    this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
}

}
```

change the fetchResponse method as below:

```
private ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> fetchResponse(String result)
    {
        ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> listParent = new ArrayList<HomeAct.CategoryParentItemList>();
        if (!result.equals(""))
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("SBL");
                CategoryParentItemList parent = null; //new
                CategoryChildListItem child = null; //new
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Categories category = new Categories();
                    parent = new CategoryParentItemList(object.getString("SubCategoryName"));
                    parent.subCategoryID = object.getInt("SubCategoryID");
                    parent.subCategoryName = object.getString("SubCategoryName");

                    System.out.println("SCI: " + object.getString("SubCategoryID"));
                    System.out.println("SCN: " + object.getString("SubCategoryName"));

                    //category.setSubCatName(object.getString("SubCategoryName"));

                    JSONArray subItemArray = object.getJSONArray("SubCategoryItemList");

                    if (subItemArray.length() > 0)
                    {
                        parent.childList=new ArrayList<HomeAct.CategoryChildListItem>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < subItemArray.length(); j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject subItemObject = subItemArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            String strItemName = subItemObject.getString("ItemName");
                            String strDefaultPrice = subItemObject.getString("DefaultPrice");

                            child = new CategoryChildListItem(strItemName, strDefaultPrice);
                            parent.childList.add(child);

                            Log.i("strItemName", strItemName);
                            Log.i("strDefaultPrice", strDefaultPrice);
                        }

                    }
                    listParent.add(parent);
                }

                //CategoryItemListAdapter adapter = new CategoryItemListAdapter(this, listParent, listChild);
                //exListCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return listParent;
    }
```

change the onPostExecute()

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);
        ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> listParent = fetchResponse(result.replace("\n","").trim());
        CategoryItemListAdapter adapter = new CategoryItemListAdapter(getActivity(), listParent);
            exListCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Also change ur adapter as below:

```
public class CategoryItemListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> parentItemLists;

    class ViewHolderGroup
    {
        TextView lblSubCategoryName;
    }

    class ViewHolderChild
    {
        TextView lblItemName;
        TextView lblDefualtPrice;
    }

    public CategoryItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryParentItemList> listParent)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.parentItemLists = listParent;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {

        return parentItemLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {

        return parentItemLists.get(groupPosition).childList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {

        return parentItemLists.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {

        return parentItemLists.get(groupPosition).childList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {

        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {

        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CategoryParentItemList parentItem = (CategoryParentItemList) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ViewHolderGroup holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header, null);
            holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
            holder.lblSubCategoryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubItemName);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.lblSubCategoryName.setText(parentItem.getSubCategoryName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CategoryChildListItem childItem = (CategoryChildListItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ViewHolderChild holder = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolderChild();
            holder.lblItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
            holder.lblDefualtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvrRupees);
        }

        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.lblItemName.setText(childItem.getSubItemName());
        holder.lblDefualtPrice.setText(childItem.getDefaultPrice());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: in above  fetchResponse() method there is you comment the line for adapter at bottom of try block . so how i call the CategoryItemListAdpater class and set it object into returnd list and required any changes in CategoryItemListAdpater  class ?

Comment: it gives error in @onPostExecute() method where we passed 1st parameter in adapter as "context (this)".

Comment: i try with passing "SlidingContentFragment.super.getActivity()" as a 1st paramter then its compile and run but at Runtime it gives error as below and crash app:

Comment: use SlidingContentFragment.this.getActivity()

Comment: its work....bt given error in CategoryItemListAdapter class attempt virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference